# Excel: 2007-2013 TypeGuessRows - Character Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel-2007

I need to import an excel 2007-2013 file into MSSQL but the characters are being truncated within a column. The quick fix is to sort the rows from largest to smallest interns of character sting length.

I require a permanent solution and the following answer (see below) worked for .exe files however what will be the corresponding solution for .xlsx files.

Thanks 
Chantelle

> To change the value of TypeGuessRows, use these steps: 1.On the Start
>   menu, click Run. In the Run dialog box, type Regedt32, and then click
>   OK. 2.Open the following key in the Registry editor:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
>
> Note For 64-bit systems, the corresponding key is as follows:
>
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\microsoft\jet\4.0\engines\excel
>   3.Double-click TypeGuessRows. 4.In the DWORD editor dialog box, click Decimal under Base. Type a value between 0 and 16, inclusive, for
>   Value data. 5.Click OK, and then exit the Registry Editor.
>
> A second way to work around this problem (without modifying the
>   registry) is to make sure that rows with fields, which have data 255
>   characters or greater, are present in the first 8 rows of the source
>   data file. shareedit
>
> answered Jan 20 '14 at 11:21
>
> Suji 112

Comment: Morning, Yes the second method did work, but this means that now I have to manually do it every time I pull in a certain report, whereas I believe the first method is a permanent solution for the problem.

Comment: Microsoft has now an official Documentation at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-the-typeguessrows-setting-for-excel-driver-6aa3e101-2a90-47ac-bf0f-7d4109a5708b