# Reading cell with Long strings from excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I am trying to load excel file with long data strings in a datatable()
Here is the sample data from excel:
[image]

when loading this data into datatable I see it loads few numbers from the Dial Codes and not loading complete data.

Here is the sample code i have written:

```
        string sheetName = null;

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            sheetName = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null)?.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            string selectCmd = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", sheetName);
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectCmd, connection))
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(fileData);
            }
        }
```

Here is the Data visualizer screenshot:
[image]

Look it has loaded few Dial Codes not all.

Please can anyone guide me whats wrong with this code? or is there anything wrong with data types i am using?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the type of the column? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408980/excel-2007-2013-typeguessrows-character-value

Comment: The column type in excel can be Text/General.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cef8693c-4812-4036-91c7-4b416b196341/excel-source-truncates-data-with-more-than-255characters?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: i'm almost sure, that all data is properly stored in your datatable, but visualizer just doesn't show all... what is normal in case of VS. read this cell value and save it into text file or read it to string variable and visualize in multi-line text box.

Comment: @MaciejS. I have to read this data into datatable and then the requirement is to separate the Dial codes and generate new rows in excel. I have tried that but its populating only what it is showing in Visualizer.

Comment: Maybe you should use externall DLL like EPPlus? It's well known and very popular library available on NuGet. with Excel files it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i have found :

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path, bool hasHeader = true)
    {
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
            }
            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
            for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                {
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
            }
            return tbl;
        }
    }
```

@Emre thank you for your efforts, you have pointed me to EPPLUS and using EP plus i have successfully implemented the solution.

Answer (score 1):

i can not read values with oledb. But i installed EPPLUS from nuget. After i read all values

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C: \Users\Emre Asus\Desktop\LongExcelDataRead-master\NoRatesFinalPL.xlsx")))
        {
           ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

            for (int i = 1; i < workSheet.Dimension.End.Row ; i++)
            {
                string value = workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: i appreciate your efforts, but it has more of the static values, like you have hard coded cells `workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString();`

Comment: Initially i tried to fetch excel rows using Datatable and oledb but wasn't able to get full-text of long string data so finally using EPPlus and above code helped.